# Не понимаю как отправлять сообщения через бота в конкретный топик

Tags: telegram-bot

Создал бота на GoogleScript.
Бот каждый день отправляет сообщение в группу для ТП "Прошу проверить принтеры".

Но он это делает в General группы, а надо чтобы он отправлял в топик Техническая поддержка.

Понимаю, что топик это обычное сообщение и всё что в нём пишут это фактически ответы на это сообщение. Тут вопрос как узнать ID этого сообщения.

Вот так написал, работает, но не в топик "Техническая поддержка":

```
function sendReminderToTelegram() {
  var telegramBotToken = "ID_BOT";
  var telegramChatId = "-100ID_CHAT";
  
  // Проверка текущего времени
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var targetTime = new Date();
  targetTime.setHours(8); // Установка желаемого часа
  targetTime.setMinutes(0); // Установка желаемых минут

  // Проверка, что текущий день недели - будний день (понедельник - пятница)
  var currentDayOfWeek = currentTime.getDay();
  var isWeekday = (currentDayOfWeek >= 1 && currentDayOfWeek <= 5);
  
  // Если текущее время соответствует целевому времени (8:00 утра) и это будний день
  if (isWeekday && currentTime.getHours() === targetTime.getHours() && currentTime.getMinutes() === targetTime.getMinutes()) {
  
    // Создание сообщения
    var message = "Прошу проверить принтеры и заправить их.";
    
    // Отправка сообщения в Telegram
    var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + telegramBotToken + "/sendMessage";
    var payload = {
      "chat_id": telegramChatId,
      "text": message,
    };
    
    var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : payload
    };
    
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(telegramUrl, options);
  //}
}
```